# Eloquent limit relationship fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following relationships:

```
TheEpisodeJob hasOne TheEpisode
TheEpisodeJob hasMany TheJobs
```

I am successfuly retrieving all `TheEpisodesJobs` and `TheSeriesEpisodes` with all the fields in database (including sensitive information) using this command:

```
$jobs = TheEpisodeJob::with('TheEpisode')->get();
```

I would like to limit `TheEpisode` fields shown only for this case (`public $hidden` will not work)

## EDIT

Let's say I need only `title` and `description` field from `TheEpisode`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What are the columns that relate `TheEpisodeJob` and `TheEpisode`? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson I am using Laravel 5.4. The column which related them is `jobID`

Comment: Just to be certain, `TheEpisodeJob` table and `TheEpisode` table both have the column `jobID`?

Comment: TheEpisodeJob has column `id` and `TheEpisode` column is `jobID`

Answer (score 4):

As @Buglinjo pointed out you can scope the relationship when eager loading, however, if you're going to be doing this to only select specific columns you must included the related column in the select so that `Eloquent` knows which Model to attach the related data to.

This should give you what you want:

```
$jobs = TheEpisodeJob::with(['TheEpisode' => function ($query) {

    $query->select('jobID', 'title', 'description');

}])->get();
```

Furthermore, if you then wanted to to get rid of the `jobID` as well you could do something like:

```
$jobs->transform(function ($job) {

    $job->TheEpisode->transform(function ($item) {
        unset($item->jobID);

        return $item;
    });

    return $job;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you, you want to limit the results according to some more parameters. If I am right, you should add more queries, like:

`->where, ->orwhere, ->select, ->whereNull`

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) is the link for more queries. Hope it will help )

I saw an update, so then you need

```
->pluck('title', 'description');
```

for more information, go to the link above

Comment: I need `title` and `description` from `TheEpisode` not from `TheEpisodeJob`

Comment: Try this:  `$results = TheEpisode::pluck('title', 'description');`

Comment: TheEpisode is a relation table to TheJobEpisode. I need to Query it from TheJobEpisode.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$jobs = TheEpisodeJob::with(['TheEpisode' => function($q){
    $q->get(['title', 'description']);
    //or
    $q->pluck('title', 'description');
}])->get();
```

Note: `pluck` is getting as array not as Eloquent Object.

Comment: ErrorException in Str.php line 72:
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: It doesn't work, in my oppinion that's because you are applying get() before `TheEpisodeJob` is a collection.

Comment: It works for me like this: `Product::whereId(1000)->with(['similar' => function($q) {
      $q->get(['position', 'product_id']);
  }])->first()`

Comment: Updated my answer. please take a look

Comment: what have been changed?

Comment: `'TheEpisode' => function($q)` this part

Comment: When I do that, the other fields are still visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136184/discussion-between-buglinjo-and-php-lover).